# Convert a matrix (full of information in columns) into a single row vector (that I can then feed to 'midi toolbox')

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I while back I asked the Matlab question:

"If I have a vector, eg '[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]'.

How can I find every possible set of a specified length within this (e.g. length = 3 -> [1 2 3], [1 2 4] ...)?

I'd like to be able to collect every one of these sets and then to find every permutation of these (I should be able to use 'perm' for this stage right?)."

@Luis Mendo suggested for the first part:

```
nchoosek([1 2 3 4 5 6 7],3)
```

producing:

```
 1     2     3/
 1     2     4/
 1     2     5/
 1     2     6/
 1     2     7/
 1     3     4/
 1     3     5/
 1     3     6/
 1     3     7/
 1     4     5/
 1     4     6/
 1     4     7/
 1     5     6/
 1     5     7/
 1     6     7/
 2     3     4/
 2     3     5/
 2     3     6/
 2     3     7/
 2     4     5/
 2     4     6/
 2     4     7/
 2     5     6/
 2     5     7/
 2     6     7/
 3     4     5/
 3     4     6/
 3     4     7/
 3     5     6/
 3     5     7/
 3     6     7/
 4     5     6/
 4     5     7/
 4     6     7/
 5     6     7/
```

...which I presume is correct, so now the next stage would be to produce an all-encompassing list of all the permutations for all of these 3 element sets.

@thewaywewalk suggested:

```
v = [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ];
n = 3;

allSets = nchoosek(v,n);

%// output in cell array
output = arrayfun(@(x) perms(allSets(x,:)),1:size(allSets,1),'Uni',0)

%// altogether
output2 = vertcat(output{:})
```

producing:

```
 3     2     1/
 3     1     2/
 2     3     1/
 2     1     3/
 1     2     3/
 1     3     2/
 4     2     1/
 4     1     2/
 2     4     1/
 2     1     4/
 1     2     4/
 1     4     2/
 5     2     1/
 5     1     2/
 2     5     1/
 2     1     5/
 1     2     5/
 1     5     2/
 6     2     1/
 6     1     2/
 2     6     1/
 2     1     6/
 1     2     6/
 1     6     2/
 7     2     1/
 7     1     2/
 2     7     1/
 2     1     7/
 1     2     7/
 1     7     2/
 4     3     1/
 4     1     3/
 3     4     1/
 3     1     4/
 1     3     4/
 1     4     3/
 5     3     1/
 5     1     3/
 3     5     1/
 3     1     5/
 1     3     5/
 1     5     3/
 6     3     1/
 6     1     3/
 3     6     1/
 3     1     6/
 1     3     6/
 1     6     3/
 7     3     1/
 7     1     3/
 3     7     1/
 3     1     7/
 1     3     7/
 1     7     3/
 5     4     1/
 5     1     4/
 4     5     1/
 4     1     5/
 1     4     5/
 1     5     4/
 6     4     1/
 6     1     4/
 4     6     1/
 4     1     6/
 1     4     6/
 1     6     4/
 7     4     1/
 7     1     4/
 4     7     1/
 4     1     7/
 1     4     7/
 1     7     4/
 6     5     1/
 6     1     5/
 5     6     1/
 5     1     6/
 1     5     6/
 1     6     5/
 7     5     1/
 7     1     5/
 5     7     1/
 5     1     7/
 1     5     7/
 1     7     5/
 7     6     1/
 7     1     6/
 6     7     1/
 6     1     7/
 1     6     7/
 1     7     6/
 4     3     2/
 4     2     3/
 3     4     2/
 3     2     4/
 2     3     4/
 2     4     3/
 5     3     2/
 5     2     3/
 3     5     2/
 3     2     5/
 2     3     5/
 2     5     3/
 6     3     2/
 6     2     3/
 3     6     2/
 3     2     6/
 2     3     6/
 2     6     3/
 7     3     2/
 7     2     3/
 3     7     2/
 3     2     7/
 2     3     7/
 2     7     3/
 5     4     2/
 5     2     4/
 4     5     2/
 4     2     5/
 2     4     5/
 2     5     4/
 6     4     2/
 6     2     4/
 4     6     2/
 4     2     6/
 2     4     6/
 2     6     4/
 7     4     2/
 7     2     4/
 4     7     2/
 4     2     7/
 2     4     7/
 2     7     4/
 6     5     2/
 6     2     5/
 5     6     2/
 5     2     6/
 2     5     6/
 2     6     5/
 7     5     2/
 7     2     5/
 5     7     2/
 5     2     7/
 2     5     7/
 2     7     5/
 7     6     2/
 7     2     6/
 6     7     2/
 6     2     7/
 2     6     7/
 2     7     6/
 5     4     3/
 5     3     4/
 4     5     3/
 4     3     5/
 3     4     5/
 3     5     4/
 6     4     3/
 6     3     4/
 4     6     3/
 4     3     6/
 3     4     6/
 3     6     4/
 7     4     3/
 7     3     4/
 4     7     3/
 4     3     7/
 3     4     7/
 3     7     4/
 6     5     3/
 6     3     5/
 5     6     3/
 5     3     6/
 3     5     6/
 3     6     5/
 7     5     3/
 7     3     5/
 5     7     3/
 5     3     7/
 3     5     7/
 3     7     5/
 7     6     3/
 7     3     6/
 6     7     3/
 6     3     7/
 3     6     7/
 3     7     6/
 6     5     4/
 6     4     5/
 5     6     4/
 5     4     6/
 4     5     6/
 4     6     5/
 7     5     4/
 7     4     5/
 5     7     4/
 5     4     7/
 4     5     7/
 4     7     5/
 7     6     4/
 7     4     6/
 6     7     4/
 6     4     7/
 4     6     7/
 4     7     6/
 7     6     5/
 7     5     6/
 6     7     5/
 6     5     7/
 5     6     7/
 5     7     6/
```

Which, it seems to me, could easily be the right answer... (@thewaywewalk if you could explain the break down of the code for me here (as though I am a small child) then that would be pretty useful?)

...My next stage is that I want to convert the whole of this into a single row vector that I can then feed to 'midi toolbox'

.. I'm currently using the below code and the output for some reason always seems to include the first element (to put things in context this is supposed to relate to musical notes (nb [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] should actually be [0 2 4 5 7 9 11], I just went for 1-7 to keep things looking simple...)  ..:

```
all_sets_major = output2 + 60 % to add 60 to every individual element
all_sets_major=all_sets_major'  %turns into columns

for o = 1:length(all_sets_Cmajor);
MIDI(o)=all_sets_Cmajor(o);
%reshapes to a single list called 'MIDI' - still a row vector - 'createnmat' takes this input
end


ee = [0:length(MIDI) - 1]' % this relates to note start time in the note matrix
%that I'm creating - the first note starts at '0' rather than 1 - so I'm taking
% every note start time back by 1

MIDI=createnmat(MIDI); %this is a Matlab function that makes a midi file out of the list
MIDI(: , 1) = ee % sets the note onset
MIDI(: , 2) = 1 % sets the duration for every note to 1 beat
MIDI(: , 3) = 1 % sets the channel for every note to channel 1
fopen('diatonic_3_note_permutations.mid')  %creates a file, will be saved in current directory
writemidi_java(MIDI, 'diatonic_3_note_permutations.mid', 100, 35, 3, 4, [1 1])
  % writes the notematrix 'Output' to a file called diatonic_3_note_permutations.mid
% writes the notematrix 'Output' to a file called diatonic_3_note_permutations.mid.
% Specifies 100 ticks per quarter, tempo - 35bpm,..., time signiature -
% 3,4, patches - [channel 1 is midi instrument 1 (piano), channel 2 is
% midi instrument 1 (piano)
fclose('all') %closes the file
```

Any ideas where I've screwed up - if you could presume complete ignorance and stupidity then that would be greatly appreciated... best wishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will address the specific problem: converting a matrix, row by row, into a single row vector. This can be done either

With the [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) command:

```
singlerow = reshape(A', 1, numel(A));
```

or by first transposing A and then using the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

```
B = A';
singlerow = B(:);
```

For example, if A is

```
 1     2     3
 1     3     2
 3     2     1
 3     1     2
```

then the singlerow is

```
 1     2     3     1     3     2     3     2     1     3     1     2
```